# How to make NO margin or spacing in between images in a gallery using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to have no space in between the images in the gallery so they are all touching. Here is my code so far.

```css
div.gallery { 
    width: 470px;
    display: inline-grid;
    
}
div.gallery img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.gallery-all {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
    <div class="gallery-all">
    <div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="img_fjords.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
</div>
    <div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="img_fjords.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
</div>
    <div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="img_fjords.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
</div>
    <div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="img_fjords.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
</div>
    
    <!-- SECOND LINE -->
    <div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="img_fjords.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
</div>
    <div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="img_fjords.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
</div>
    <div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="img_fjords.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
</div>
    <div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="img_fjords.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
div.gallery { 
    width: 470px;
    display: inline-grid;
    
}
div.gallery img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
margin-bottom: -5px;
}

.gallery-all {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
    <div class="gallery-all">
    <div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="img_fjords.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
</div>
    <div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="img_fjords.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
</div>
    <div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="img_fjords.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
</div>
    <div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="img_fjords.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
</div>
    
    <!-- SECOND LINE -->
    <div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="img_fjords.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
</div>
    <div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="img_fjords.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
</div>
    <div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="img_fjords.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
</div>
    <div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="img_fjords.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you that worked with the top and bottom line but it didnt with the left and right images

Comment: maybe so: 
div.gallery img {
    width: 470px;
    height: auto;
margin-bottom: -5px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
}